# Jquery $toggle(''slow") showing flickering/stuck behavior?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-animations

**Problem**
.toggle('slow') transition is behaving weirdly, its flickering before hiding and showing , probably due to the way my code is set up and maybe not be efficient.

**Full Details**
i have a basic setup where i am showing/hiding  more/less list based on how many lists are going to be there, because eventually when the data comes from the back end we wouldn't know. Since div jumping is not a good user experience i added a .toggle('slow') so that the height gets adjusted nicely. but as you can see in the demo this is displaying a buggy like behavior to were showing and hiding list is flicering.

```css
.product-promotion-display {
    background: linear-gradient(90deg, #d4272e 50%, #fff 50%);
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: height 1s ease;
  }
  .product-promotion-display ._see-more-li {
    list-style: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: underline;

  }
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Products slider</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO"
  crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
  <link href="http://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js" integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy"
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49"
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


</head>

<body>

  <div class="product-promotion-display border">

    <div class="container">

      <div class="row pt-5">
        <div class="col-sm text-white pb-3">
          <h1 class="pb-4">Cable Tray - FTE FRP</h1>
          <P class="pb-2">Ideal
            Ideal for applications that require high strength in high corrosion resistance. The tray system has 2
            types: 50
            and 80 mm heights that are extremely ﬂexible. </P>
          <h5 class="pb-1">Advantages:</h5>
          <ul class=" pl-0">
            <li class="pb-2 ml-5">
              Easy to cut
            </li>
            <li class="pb-2 ml-5">
              No hot work permit required
            </li>
            <li class="pb-2 ml-5">
              Simple hand tools used for cutting and drilling
            </li>
            <li class="pb-2 ml-5">
              FRP oﬀers a Long Life Cycle
            </li>
            <li class="pb-2 ml-5">
              FRP oﬀers a Long Life Cycle
            </li>
            <li class="pb-2 ml-5">
              FRP oﬀers a Long Life Cycle
            </li>
            <li class="pb-2 ml-5">
              FRP oﬀers a Long Life Cycle
            </li>
            <li class="pb-2 ml-5">
              FRP oﬀers a Long Life Cycle
            </li>
            <li class="pb-2 ml-5">
              FRP oﬀers a Long Life Cycle
            </li>
          </ul>


          <div class="btn-group pt-2 pb-5">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-light mr-5">Request A Quote</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-light">Shop Online</button>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm ppd-img-div align-self-center">
          <img src="./images/toolbox.png" alt="there was an image" class="img-fluid">
        </div>
      </div>


    </div>

  </div>


  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
      $('ul').each(function () {
        var max = 4
        if ($(this).find('li').length > max) {
          $(this).find('li:gt(' + max + ')').hide().end().append('<li class="_see-more-li pl-0 ml-0 pt-3"><h5 class="_see-more-text">Read More</h5></li>');
          $('._see-more-li').click(function () {
            $(this).siblings(':gt(' + max + ')').toggle('slow');
            if ($('._see-more-text').length) {
              $(this).html('<h5 class="show_less">Read Less</h5>');
            } else {
              $(this).html('<h5 class="_see-more-text">Read More</h5>');
            };
          });
        };
      });


    })
  </script>


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are setting the list items to display: none, when you display none it hides the whole item, so when you want to show it, it shows all the items (padding) first and then it starts the transition of the actual text.

You should play with the height of the the items, set the height to 0 to hide it, and when you want to show it, set it to height: auto.